# How can I start the default file manager from terminal?

Tags: command-line, file-management

I have X11 Forwarding on, and want to use a graphical interface to manage files.

How can I start the default file manager over ssh?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use the prefered file manager you can use `xdg-open`, to open for example the file manager in `Projects/` you can use `xdg-open Projects/`

Source : [xdg-open](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open)

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this.

Comment: To open the current directory, you can use `xdg-open .`

Answer (score 11):

The file manager is `pantheon-files`, so simply running

```
pantheon-files
```

works. Because `pantheon-files` does not run in the background by default and generates plenty of terminal output:

```
huey@galactica:~$ pantheon-files
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 11:43:27.546677] Application.vala:155: Files version: 0.2.1
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 11:43:27.546761] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.8.11
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 11:43:27.718180] Application.vala:84: Report any issues/bugs you might find to http://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 11:43:27.722268] [libnotify] Failed to connect to proxy
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 11:43:27.806887] [dconf] failed to commit changes to dconf: GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code2: Failed to create file: Permission denied
```

I chose instead to run it in `screen` instead.

Comment: To get rid of the debug output, run `pantheon-files 2>/dev/null`. To run it in the background, add `&` at the end of the command line.

Comment: Elementary OS 6 works with `io.elementary.files` as said by @Jay Aurabind

Answer (score 9):

Starting with Juno release, the commands have all changed. They're adopting RDNN. For files:

`io.elementary.files`

Answer (score 0):

The use of `io.elementary` or `io.pantheon`, etc just complicates things. It's much easier to do a `#gedit file.txt` than `#io.elementary.code file.txt`. Oh well...